# Getting Team Members In a Specific Team in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this Teams table (can be a Projects Table as well) and Members table

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| team_name | varchar(100) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| team_desc | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| createdby | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and Members table

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| firstname   | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lastname    | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address     | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| city        | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| state       | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| country     | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email       | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| phone       | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| experience  | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| designation | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| username    | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password    | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and these two tables are joined by this teams_members table,

```
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| teams_members_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| teams_id         | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| members_id       | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What I want to do is get members in a specific team. I am quite confused how I am gonna do this (may be I am dumb :P)

```
SELECT * 
FROM teams_members tm, members m, teams t 
WHERE tm.members_member_id = m.id 
AND t.team_name='team name can be anything'
AND tm.id = t.id
```

It returns 0 results. Where I might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query the `join with teams_member and team` is **incorrect**:

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM teams_members tm, members m, teams t 
WHERE tm.members_member_id = m.id 
AND t.team_name='team name can be anything'
AND tm.teams_id = t.id
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * 
FROM teams_members tm
inner join members m on tm.member_id=m.id
inner join teams t on tm.teams_id=t.id
WHERE 
t.team_name='team name can be anything'
```

Comment: I was actually thinking to use `INNER JOIN`. That did the trick thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you are open to use nested query:

```
    select *
    from Members
    where id in(
                 select members_id
                 from team_members
                 where teams_id in(
                                   select id
                                   from teams
                                   where team_name='anything'))
```